# Electronic Design Book

Tags: design

I'd like to know if there are books about how to design electronic circuits.  I have lots of theoretical books that cover how to analyse circuits, but I'd like to read about something more practical, like how to actually design something and what to look out for.  So for example, in my circuit theory books, say like Sedra And Smith, they analyse, say, Cascode amplifiers and come up with large convoluted expressions for things like gain and input and output resistance; it seems like it's impossible to really use those equations to design anything (though they are helpful in understand the circuit).  I guess I'd basically like a book that goes through the design of standard building block circuits, like differential amplifiers with current sources and active mirrors and multistage amplifiers etc.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite book for this is "Practical Electronics for Inventors". $20.00 on Amazon and is a fantastic reference:

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Electronics-Inventors-Third-Edition/dp/0071771336/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1377754210&sr=8-1&keywords=practical+electronics+for+inventors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071771336)

This book has a lot of breadth and covers many simple building blocks and provides good first order approximations on how to apply basic circuits. It's meant for people just starting out and does not go into any detail about specific topics. The circuits are very basic but after reading this you should have a better idea of what book you want to go for next. This book will only cover topics you learn in the first two years of any decent EE program.

Other classical texts to consider:

The Art of Electronics, by Horowitz and Hill
Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits, by Anant Agarwal